# How can I record constant values on omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

How can I get constant values from a message and show these values in a result (histogram)?

My message structure is:

```
message msgCLAS
{
   int Singclas = 2206;
   int Singlial = 3009;
   int Verifclas = 5403;
   int Veriflial = 6406;
   int Aggreclas = 2;
   int Aggrelial = 2;
   int Verifagclas = 1833;
   int Verifaglial = 1857;     
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it's just not clear from your question what you want to achieve.

Comment: i would like to make "Figure 3: Computation cost comparisons" on page 10  of the pdf document, in oment++ (https://files.fm/u/y6devjwhw)       .how i can do this figure in omnet++??thanks